# Force label float when no input data in Angular Material

Tags: angular-material

In Angular Material, the default design of input directives is for the content within `<label>` to be displayed in the input element until the user enters some input, at which point it will float above the input element, as seen in all examples [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input).

Is there any way to force the labels to float above the input box at all times instead, even when no data has been entered?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the css class `md-input-has-placeholder` is what you need:

```
<md-input-container class="md-input-has-placeholder">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text"/>
</md-input-container>
```

Plunker example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/WiPV7imxuv3KoHamsBfI?p=preview)

Hope it helps.

Comment: what about for an md-select? how do you make it stay at the top?

Comment: Never mind got it to work by changing the label to a Placeholder

Comment: @Flash Any chance you can share your code? I'd like to build a demo for it.

Comment: Sure @TopherFangio

Answer (score 3):

The is an official feature for that: floatLabel="always"

The **floatLabel** property of  can be used to change this default floating behavior. It can set to **never** to hide the label instead of float it when text is present in the form field control. It can be set to **always** to float the label even when no text is present in the form field control. It can also be set to **auto** to restore the default behavior.

```
<mat-form-field floatLabel="always">
    <mat-label>Both a label and a placeholder</mat-label>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="model.value">
</mat-form-field>
```

source, see the [official form-field documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview)

Answer (score 1):

With Md-select this worked for me:

```
 <md-input-container style="width: 200px;" md-input-has-placeholder>
                  <placeholder>Snack Types </placeholder>
                    <md-select ng-model="selectedOption">
                        <md-option  ng-repeat="item in snacks" >
                            {{item.name}}
                        </md-option>
                    </md-select>
 </md-input-container>
```

Comment: Should that be `class="md-input-has-placeholder"`?

Comment: No it doesn't have to be but it should still work either way

Answer (score 1):

For the md-select element, occupy the following:

```html
<md-input-container class="md-input-has-placeholder">
    <label md-no-float="true" class="md-required">Snack Types</label>
    <md-select ng-model="$ctrl.selection" ng-required="true" md-no-asterisk>
        <md-option ng-value="option.id" ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.selection">{{ opcion.value}}</md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

I used the following CSS to change the label when data is being entered and highlight the other fields:

```css
md-input-container:focus-within > label[class~="md-required"]{
    transform: scale(1);
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

And the following CSS so that the asterisk is always in color (you can put the color you want):

```css
md-input-container.md-default-theme:not(.md-input-focused):not(.md-input-invalid) label.md-required:after, md-input-container:not(.md-input-focused):not(.md-input-invalid) label.md-required:after{
    color: rgb(255,87,10);
}
```